# how to overwrite the rows of df1 which has matching row with df2 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have Two Data Frames df1 and df2
i want to overwrite rows which are same in both the DataFrame.
I want to overwrite matching row of df1 with df2 after combining
here is my data

```
df1
Date         Value      Indicator   Frequency   Measure   Unit
2002-08-21  89.46308725 KN.A10         W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100
2002-08-28  91.92630872 KN.A10         W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-04  93.15436242 KN.A10         W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-11  93.69127517 KN.A10         W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-18  94.89932886 KN.A10         W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100

df2
Date         Value          Indicator      Frequency          Measure        Unit
2002-08-21  21.236          KN.A11              A             KN.M4   index, 2000 = 100
2002-08-28  91.94630872     KN.A10              W             KN.M3   index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-04  24.589          KN.A11              A             KN.M4   index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-11  62.254          KN.A11              A             KN.M4   index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-18  15.254          KN.A11              A             KN.M4   index, 2000 = 100

After Appending df1 and df2 my Data should be like this 
df3
Date        Value       Indicator   Frequency   Measure     Unit
2002-08-21  21.236       KN.A11        A        KN.M4     index, 2000 = 100
2002-08-28  91.94630872  KN.A10        W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-04  24.589       KN.A11        A        KN.M4     index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-11  62.254       KN.A11        A        KN.M4     index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-18  15.254       KN.A11        A        KN.M4     index, 2000 = 100
2002-08-21  89.46308725  KN.A10        W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-04  93.15436242  KN.A10        W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-11  93.69127517  KN.A10        W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100
2002-09-18  94.89932886  KN.A10        W        KN.M3     index, 2000 = 100
```

As it is shown in the df3 . I want to overwrite the matching rows of df1 with df2 by df2 value after appending/ combining df1 and df2.So that I should not Get duplicate Rows

I want to overwrite because the column value may vary.
Please Help .I was searching for the solution but coulnd find the better solution for  this ..
The Overwritten row in df3 is in second row(2nd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) or [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
pd.concat([df2,df1]).drop_duplicates(subset = ['Date','Indicator'],keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)
#pd.concat([df2,df1]).groupby(['Date','Indicator'],as_index=False).first()

         Date      Value Indicator Frequency Measure            Unit
0  2002-08-21  21.236000    KN.A11         A   KN.M4  index,2000=100
1  2002-08-28  91.946309    KN.A10         W   KN.M3  index,2000=100
2  2002-09-04  24.589000    KN.A11         A   KN.M4  index,2000=100
3  2002-09-11  62.254000    KN.A11         A   KN.M4  index,2000=100
4  2002-09-18  15.254000    KN.A11         A   KN.M4  index,2000=100
0  2002-08-21  89.463087    KN.A10         W   KN.M3  index,2000=100
2  2002-09-04  93.154362    KN.A10         W   KN.M3  index,2000=100
3  2002-09-11  93.691275    KN.A10         W   KN.M3  index,2000=100
4  2002-09-18  94.899329    KN.A10         W   KN.M3  index,2000=100
```